# What options are there to administrate a database for an online business?

Tags: database, project-management, data

Say you create a small online business from scratch, a nice Rails or  Django app or something to that effect.

With luck, you end up with a database full of customer orders and things.

Now, aside from manually with code or the DB's own interface, how do people administrate this? What do people use? Surely everytime an order is marked completed, people don't log into the database and issue an UPDATE with SQL. They have some kind of administration interface.

At larger companies of course they build their own internal tools for this sort of thing. But for small solo developers who have created a small service, what options are there?

(I'm new to this side of things, I'm not sure what terms to use to google this subject.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A web shop does not only consist of the shop that's visible to customers. It also needs a back-office or administration interface where orders and products can be managed. This is completely invisible to customers.

When designing such a system, it is easy to forget back-office functionality because you don't usually see this. However, this is an important part of the system that must also be built in some form. This isn't a large company vs. solo developer problem. If that solo developer is able to implement a “buy now” button, they can also implement an internal order management page.

Of course, many businesses use existing e-commerce solutions that have all of this built-in, instead of developing their own application. Such existing solutions range from Wordpress plugins, over webshop SaaS companies like Shopify, to selling on platforms like the Amazon Marketplace.